Parts of Google Pay api no longer exist and I cant work aroud a solution to add and Initialize the google pay button
I dont really know what to do, I have been trying to set up google pay for my app so that the user could checkout, but this doesnt seem to work, i was able to add the google pay button to my xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:wallet="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#303030"
    >
<LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.wallet.button.PayButton
            android:id="@+id/google_pay_buttonLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

I am following the documentaion which says to create a checkout activity, i do the same but in the end of the documentation they give their full code fore CechoutActivity and in the imports you can see:
import com.google.android.gms.samples.pay.R;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.pay.databinding.ActivityCheckoutBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.pay.util.PaymentsUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.samples.pay.viewmodel.CheckoutViewModel;

all of which DO NOT EXIST, yet they play vital role in the whole checkout activity.
I have found a solution to something similar, in my PaymentsUtil file, as i followed the doc, they sayed to use some sort of CONSTANTS in createPaymentClient, later i found it should be replaced with WalletAConstants, but i still dont know what to replace the imports above with. I have looked all aroud the internet but to no avail, i have tried adding viewBinding and dataBinding and other stuff to my gradle file:
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled true
    }

...

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.4.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-pay:16.5.0"

heres a link to the documentation:Google Pay api
Thanks to anybody who can help

if you follow the tutorial step by step, you'll see every class and variable are defined, and you can find a sample file with all the constants in the sample open source repo.
The full example follows a basic ViewModel architecture, yet it essentially replicates what you see in the step by step guide.
In summary:

.R import: That's basically a programmatic link to your Android resources, and it is based on your project's package name. For example, if your package name is com.alon.app, your R import would be com.alon.app.R.
View binding: This is an API feature/library on Android that simplifies working with views in your application. Using view binding is not necessary to integrate Google Pay. If you decide to use it in your app, the import will be based out of your app's package name, and the name of your XML layout. Take a look at the docs to learn more about view binding.
The PaymentsUtil class is a simple utility class to create objects needed for the Google Pay API, and organize logic away from the main view and view model classes. A utility class is not necessary to integrate Google Pay, and you can organize your logic however you prefer in your application.
The ViewModel class refers to the ViewModel architectural pattern referred to above. In this example you'll see calls to the Google Pay API (isReadyToPay and loadPaymentData) are being issued from the view model.

As you can see you can organize and architect your application however is most convenient to you. For a simple vanilla integration, I recommend you follow the step by step tutorial, which is architecture/principle agnostic. The open source sample repository contains a very simple application following basic recommended Android practices, like a view model architecture, or view binding.
